# Where to put application settings in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, properties

I wondered what is the prefered place to put application wide presettings in JSF. I see 3 options:

1. web.xml
2. properties file with `<resource-bundle>` configuration in faces-config.xml
3. properties file and use it per `java.util.Properties`

I would prefer Nr. 2, because it seems to be most straightforward and easiest to use. But I am not sure if this is good, because in general I thought `<resource-bundle>` is planed for localized messages and not for application wide settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option #1 and #2 have the advantage that you can also easily access the settings via EL. With option #1 you can do `#{initParam['keyUsedForContextParam']}`. With option #2 you can go the normal way for resource bundles `#{rscBundleName['keyUsedInPropertiesFile']}`. But as you already said: Most of the time you will use that for localization, so it will be a bit weird, but it would work. But for application wide settings, I think the web.xml with custom `context-params` would probably be the more appropriate way.

If you want to access the settings in your managed bean, you will have to access the settings via the FacesContext. For option #1 that might look like `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("keyUsedForContextParam");`. This is not that nice.

Option #3 Also works of course, but you would need some kind of `@ApplicationScoped` utility bean, which will access the settings from your custom `.properties`-file. But that's actually not a very big problem. You could access the settings via EL like this: `#{settingsBean.get('keyUsedInPropertiesFile')}`. This is more obvious than `initParam` for example. In your managed beans you can also just inject your `SettingsBean` and access the settings the same way. Most easy to understand.

Option #3 also has a big not that obvious advantage. You can re-read the settings in real time. The web.xml and the resource bundles defined in the faces-config.xml will only be read on startup. The `SettingsBean` might re-read the .properties file every time and you would be able to change settings on-the-fly (make it `@RequestScoped`). The bean alternative is also more powerful in general, you might for example define default-settings which apply when you do not define any value in your properties file and so on.

I'd advise you to go with Option #3.

Answer (score 4):

> *web.xml*

I gather you mean `<context-param>`? This is usually to be used for configuration parameters of servlet/filter based 3rd party libraries (JSF API/impl, PrimeFaces, OmniFaces, Jersey, etc).

---

> *properties file with `<resource-bundle>` configuration in `faces-config.xml`*

This is usually to be used for localization of JSF pages, i.e. being able to switch to a completely different language site-wide.

---

> *properties file and use it per java.util.Properties*

This is usually to be used for name=value pairs which can represent anything like localized text and configuration settings.

---

You see, there's not really a "which should I use" case here. The question "when should I use it" was been more appropriate. The answer is ultimately, just use the right tool for the job.